# JQuery .index() doesn't return the right index for the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing

at first my HTML:

```
<h2>
  <a href=[...]>
    <expander>
      SomeText
</expander>
  </a>
</h2>

<h2>
  <a href=[...]>
    <expander>
      SomeText
</expander>
  </a>
</h2>
```

Now the Javascript/JQuery:

```
$("expander").on("click", function(){
    var blubb = $(this).index();
            alert(blubb)
});
```

My problem is that the "alert" (so in fact the "blubb" var) throws zero all the time. Shouldn't it give "1" if I click the second expander?

Thanks!

Regards

Comment: No, because They have different parents, you should apply it to the `<h2>`

Comment: Ah right... Thanks! Arun worked me around there :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `expander` is the first and only child of its parent index will always return `0`.

Try this:

```
var blubb = $(this).closest('h2').index();
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/CbKPt/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this to get the proper index of `expander` clicked:

```
$("expander").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var blubb = $("expander").index(this);
    alert(blubb)
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7cSST/)

Answer (score 0):

`.index()` without any arguments will give the index of the element with relation to its siblings

In your case you need to find the index of clicked expander relative to the expander elements in the page, so try

```
var $expanders = $("expander").on("click", function(){
    var blubb = $expanders.index(this);
    alert(blubb)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q6BXT/)

Comment: WOW! Worked! Thanks! Makes sense btw ;P

Comment: @user176270 As you're new to Stackoverflow: If this answer helped you most, please use the green checkmark to accept it. It will help future visitors to see, which one solved your problem.